# Weighted ggplot2 warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: weight

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, warnings

I try to plot a weighted density with ggplot2. The results seem to be fine, but I get the following warning: `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: weight`. Similar problems seem to appear in [other ggplot2 applications](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2204) and therefore I am wondering, if the warning could be ignored.

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

# Some random data & weights
x <- rnorm(1000, 5)
w <- x^5

# Plot unweighted
ggplot() + stat_density(aes(x = x))

# Plot weighted - Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: weight
ggplot() + stat_density(aes(x = x, weight = w / sum(w))) # Weighting seems to work fine

# Comparison of weighted density in base graphics - Same results as with ggplot2
plot(density(x, weights = w / sum(w)))
```

Can this warning message be ignored?

Comment: You could try `options(warn=-1)`?  ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45178787/3526832))

Comment: @h3rm4n You should never do that. Use `suppressWarnings` if needed. Anyway, this should be submitted to the ggplot2 bug tracker (if it hasn't been submitted yet).

Comment: @h3rm4n I do not care that the warning is shown, I just want to make sure that my results are correct.

Comment: @Roland What is the "ggplot2 bug tracker" and where can I find it? Would you agree that my results are valid, even though I receive a warning message?

Comment: @Roland Why is that? For the reason as mentioned in the linked source?

Comment: The reason you are getting this warning is that ggplot2 doesn't have a `weight` aestetic AFAIK (which is what the warning message is trying to tell you)

Comment: @JoachimSchork You can find the link at the [ggplot2 CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html). I give no warranties for correctness, even for my own packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the warning by using `geom_density`:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(x = x, weight = w / sum(w)), color = "green") +
  geom_density(aes(x = x), color = "blue")
```

[image: resulting plot]

I would have expected the `stat_` function to handle the same aesthetics as the geom and it appears to do so. The warning would then be a bug that should be reported to the maintainers.

Comment: Thanks, yes seems like stat_ also works, but geom_ seems to be preferable!

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not your get a warning appears to depend on where you give the weight argument (ggplot2 version 2.2.1):

Following these answers:
[Create weighted histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841204/create-a-histogram-for-weighted-values?noredirect=1&lq=1), 
[Histogram with weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355938/histogram-with-weights-in-r)

Setup data:

```
w = seq(1,1000)
v = sort(runif(1000))
foo = data.frame(v,w)
```

The following command **produces** a warning:

```
ggplot(foo) + geom_histogram(aes(v, weight=w),bins = 30)
```

These commands **do not produce** a warning:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(v, weight=w)) + geom_histogram(bins = 30)
ggplot(foo, aes(weight=w)) + geom_histogram(aes(v),bins = 30)
```

But all three commands produce the same plot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x = x, weight=w/sum(w))) + stat_density()
```

And:

```
ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x = x, weight=w/sum(w))) + 
   stat_density(fill=NA, color = "green") + 
   stat_density(aes(x=x), fill=NA, color = "blue", inherit.aes=F)
```

[image]